# When Matrix.Invert(mymatrix) give a "Not a number" matrix

Tags: c#, matrix, xna

I calculate a transform Matrix like this:

```
Matrix blockTransform =
    Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-obj.Origin, 0.0f)) *
    Matrix.CreateScale(obj.Scale.X, obj.Scale.Y, 0.0f) *
    Matrix.CreateRotationZ(obj.Rotation) *
    Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(obj.Position, 0.0f));
```

Then, if I calculate this:

```
Matrix inverted = Matrix.Invert(blockTransform);
```

And I go to see its content, by writing it on console, or by setting a breakpoint near, I see that every element of mymatrix is "Not a number".

Why? Is this because blockTransform isn't invertible? How can I solve this?

**Edit:** In fact blockTransform's determinant is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found: I had to put `1.0f` as Z scale factor instead of `0.0f`.